# Subtract costs from the max profit or factor-in costs into the objective function?

Tags: linear-programming

I have the following model with profit being these selling prices for V and C:
£3.5V + £5.2C.

But there are also costs of V & C which are £1.30 and £1.70 respectively.
When I run the model without costs I get:
V=30.77 units, C=0 units, max profit=£107.69.
Then I subtract the costs of £40.00 giving a net profit of **£67.69**.

```
Max Profit)   3.5V + 5.2C
Subject To
IngredientA) 0.52V + 0.82C <= 16
IngredientB) 0.83V + 0.31C <= 28   
OvenCap)         V + C     <= 45
Contract)        V         >= 15
END
```

But when I run the model factoring in costs in the OF I get:
V=15 units, C=10 units, max profit=**£68.00**.

```
Max Profit)   2.2V + 3.5C
    Subject To
    IngredientA) 0.52V + 0.82C <= 16
    IngredientB) 0.83V + 0.31C <= 28   
    OvenCap)         V + C     <= 45
    Contract)        V         >= 15
    END
```

Both are very close in profit but units are totally different. Are both acceptable? The homework question mentions rounding off decimals to two places and only the first model actually has decimals so I'm thinking I should use that one, but it doesn't seem right to do another step of subtracting costs from the profit after running the model. It seems the model should be run on the profit factoring in the costs at the same time.

I'm thinking both are acceptable in terms of homework and the teacher is just saying to round off to two decimals incase we used the first version, but I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i did read 3,5 times ^^

i run it too

2nd model(only proper model)
**V,C=integers**

```
Max Profit)   2.2V + 3.5C
    Subject To
    IngredientA) 0.52V + 0.82C <= 16
    IngredientB) 0.83V + 0.31C <= 28   
    OvenCap)         V + C     <= 45
    Contract)        V         >= 15
    END
```

results (as yours):
V=15 units, C=10 units, max profit=£68.00.

did run same model but obj fun an

```
Max,   3.5V + 5.2C
and added V>=0 and C>=0
```

Result - Optimal solution found
Objective value:                106.70000000
V=29.0
C=1.0

you results
V=30.77 units, C=0 units, max profit=**£107.69.**
You have higher profit then me, but look your V=30.77 units - its not integer (i guess real .. you forget to set proper type

"Both are very close in profit but units are totally different. Are both acceptable? The homework question mentions rounding off decimals to two places and only the first model actually has decimals so I'm thinking I should use that one, but it doesn't seem right to do another step of subtracting costs from the profit after running the model. It seems the model should be run on the profit factoring in the costs at the same time."

**but it doesn't seem right to do another step of subtracting costs from the profit after running the model.**
yes you are right-its just luck its little close to optimal, but its pure luck...

**It seems the model should be run on the profit factoring in the costs at the same time.**
yes, my advice, dont ever think about "math after optimal results" :D its just lucky that results are close to optimum

you are simply right, do proper modelling, stick to it :-)

Comment: Thank you. I am glad my intuition was right. We must do everything in the model.  No math after the model!!! I think my professor was trying to trick us by asking us to round to two decimals. The optimal model does not have decimals. That is very coincidental that both models are so close.

Comment: @Edison im happy you happy that post did help ^^

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. I set to integer just now and also got `106.70000000 V=29.0 C=1.0`. But it doesn't matter because no matter what, `Max =  2.2V + 3.5C` is the correct OF.

Comment: @Edison good that results are the same :D yes :-)